# How to revert update query in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-update, revert

I am using SQL Server for my database. now there is table which has following columns.

```
PK_ID   FK_ID   Name   Description
1        5       ABC      ABCDE
2        7       EFG      EFT
3        8       XUZ      Xyz
4        11      TEF      TEF
```

Now by mistake i update some Fk_ID field with null value. Now I want to get back my all fk_id which is updated by null value. So is there any way to revert back fk_id's which has value previously?

Can any one help me out to find out solution for the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid this in the future, you may want to use a transaction to give you the option to roll back.

For example

```
BEGIN TRAN T1;
UPDATE ImportantStuff SET ImportantValue = 1 WHERE SomeValue = 5
```

You can then either commit if it looks good:

```
COMMIT TRAN T1;
```

Or rollback if it doesn't

```
ROLLBACK TRAN T1
```

Of course, this is not a substitute for testing before you run a script against real data - but I have often used this during testing, rather than hoping for the best.

Without a transaction, you will need to reset the data from a back up.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't an easy way to do this. Restore from Backup.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to restore from backup, if you have it.  There is no way to get that data back otherwise.

In order to avoid the problem in the future, use transactions and foreign key constraints.